# Explicitly forbid a concrete class template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, class-template

I have a class template:

```
template< typename ...bounded_types >
struct variant {};
```

But want to forbid empty list of bounded types, i.e. `variant<>` must be forbidden at compile time. I can do the following:

```
template<>
struct variant<>;
```

But it is not too clear: if my *variant* library contain a plenty of headers, then it is not evident, whether above specialization is not the **forward declaration** of a class, defined somewhere below. At my mind, ideal imaginary solution will be:

```
template<>
struct variant<> = delete;
```

This looks in greater extent explicitly, but sadly, in turn, forbidden by C++ syntax.

What is the most explicit way to satisfy the intentions described?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<typename... bounded_types>
struct variant {
    static_assert(sizeof...(bounded_types) > 0, "empty variant is illegal");
};
```

See how it fails: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c08bee816d2bc36c
See how it succeeds: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b34ece864f770d24

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you may do

```
template<typename T, typename ...bounded_types >
struct variant
{};
```

Comment: This approach entail very hard complication of the `variant`'s design.